# Correct way to inherit an S4 object in another S4 Object in R

Tags: r, object, oop, r-s4

I want to create an S4 class with one slot as another S4 class. Following is the simplified version of the code,

##### Definition of Class 1

```
setClass(
 "class1",
    representation(
     class1_vector = "character",
     class1_vector2 = "numeric"
   )
)
```

##### Definition of another class that inherits Class 1

```
setClass(
 "class2",
 
 # Inheritance of class 1
 contains = c("class1"),

 # Slots
   representation(
        class1_object = "class1", # Slot of Class 1
        class2.frame = "data.frame"
    )
)
```

I only want to create object 2 using a function as follows. This function only asks for slots for class-2

```
some.function <- function(df){

    # Create an object for class1
    object.class1 <- new("class1",
       class1_vector = as.character(NULL),
       class1_vector2 = as.numeric(NULL)
                     )

   # Create an Object for class2 with the object of class1
    object.class2 <- new("class2",
        class1_object = object.class1,
        class2.frame = df)

   return(object.class2)
}
```

##### Returned Object

```
obj <- some.function(df = data.frame(colName = c(1,2,3)))
```

Upon viewing the obj in R-studio, I see two additional slots of `class1` in `obj`.
**class1_vector** and **class1_vector2** are the slots from *Class1*.
[image]

why do they exist as a slot of both *Class1* and *Class2*? I want to make the object with all slots of *Class1.Object* as null in the beginning.

Is there a correct way to do this? Where I am going wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining `class2` as a *type of* `class1`, since by specifying `contains = c("class1")` you are specifically telling `setClass` that you want `class2` to inherit the slots from `class1`. In other words, you want `class2` to have the slots called `class1_vector` and `class1_vector2`.

But *in addition*, your definition is specifying that you want `class2` to have a slot that contains a `class1` object. This is nothing to do with inheritance, and nothing to do with the `contains` parameter of `setClass`. You simply have one class in the member slot of another class.

If all you want is for `class2` to contain a `class1` object in a slot, simply remove `contains = c("class1")` from the definition of `class2`

```r
setClass(
  "class2",
  
  # Slots
  representation(
    class1_object = "class1", # Slot of Class 1
    class2.frame = "data.frame"
  )
)
```

So now when you do

```r
obj <- some.function(df = data.frame(colName = c(1,2,3)))
```

You get this:

```r
View(obj)
```

[image]